# ASP.net authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, salt

Im a CS major and I just got done designing an ASP.net site, and for the site I needed a login authentication system... I didn't want to use SQLMembershipProvider as I really wanted to learn how to make one on my own... Anyways this is what I came up with, and I was wondering if anyone can give me some feedback, tips, or advice.

Thanks in Advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for PwEncrypt
/// </summary>
public class PwEncrypt
{
    public const int DefaultSaltSize = 5;

    private static string CreateSalt()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DefaultSaltSize];
        rng.GetBytes(buffer);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
    }

    public static string CreateHash(string password, out string salt)
    {
        salt = CreateSalt();
        string saltAndPassword = String.Concat(password, salt);
        string hashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltAndPassword, "SHA1");
        hashedPassword = string.Concat(hashedPassword, salt);
        return hashedPassword;
    }
       public static string CreateHashAndGetSalt(string password, string salt)
    {

        string saltAndPassword = String.Concat(password, salt);
        string hashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltAndPassword, "SHA1");
        hashedPassword = string.Concat(hashedPassword, salt);
        return hashedPassword;
    }

    public static bool comparePassword(string insertedPassword, string incUserName, out string newEncryptedPassword, out string originalPassword)
    {
        databaseInteraction DBI = new databaseInteraction();
        string actualPassword ="";
        string salt = "";


        DBI.getSaltandPassword(incUserName, out salt, out actualPassword);
        string hashedIncPassword = PwEncrypt.CreateHashAndGetSalt(insertedPassword, salt);
       // hashedIncPassword = string.Concat(hashedIncPassword, salt);     
        newEncryptedPassword = hashedIncPassword;
        originalPassword = actualPassword;
        if (newEncryptedPassword == originalPassword)
        {

            return true;
        }

        else { return false; }

    }
```

Comment: If you want to create custom membership provider, you first have to inherit from MemberShipProvider. And this is quite well documented if you google a bit.

Comment: Don’t attempt to roll your own custom authentication and session management schemes or build your own controls unless you really have no other choice. I just want to do it, doesn't qualify. An interesting read: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html

Comment: @ChristopheGeers Exactly... It's pretty cumbersome to do it yourself, the built in MembershipProviders work well, they jut have to be configured to do so.

Comment: I understand that for a production site, this would indeed be the case but for educational purposes do you truly believe that only knowing how to implement an authentication system via a pre-constructed system is a good thing? Since I clearly mentioned the MembershipProviders I clearly knew what it was and am quite comfortable using it, but not every language has it... I was simply asking for advice or tips on implementing a custom system for the purposes of education  OUTSIDE asp.net. As far as cumbersome to do it yourself, that's not really an issue as long as it may have some benefit later.

Comment: @user1474120 - Except your implementation security wise is a nightmare.  Your password hashing is not sure.

Comment: @Ramhound - I agree that it may be a nightmare, which is why i was asking for tips on an implementation outside of membershipProvider much like the person who is answering below is doing... As I said, im a student and am trying to learn how to do it outside of membershipProvider for whenever I need to use a language that doesn't have it. If you have some advice on how I can improve the implementation outside of using membershipProvider, I'd love to hear it. I'd like to think for a first attempt and as a very small part of a project I designed I did an ok job.. But I do want to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a table for accounts like this
[image]

Then you can create some helper class that returns an account object

```
private static Account GetByName(string accountName, bool activatedOnly = false)
{
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    {
        return context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(s => 
            s.AccountName == accountName &&
            s.IsApproved == activatedOnly);
    }
}

public static Account Get(string accountName, string password)
{
    var account = GetByName(accountName, true);
    if (account != null)
        if (!Cryptographer.IsValidPassword(password, 
                                           account.PasswordSalt, 
                                           account.PasswordKey))
            return null;
    return account;
}
```

I'm using `EntityFramework` but it's not important here. The main idea is show that you don't need to get the whole list of accounts (especially if you have a big list of users). 
My `Cryptographer` class looks like

```
public class Cryptographer
{
    private const int keyByteLength = 20;
    public static void Encrypt(string password, 
                               out byte[] salt,
                               out byte[] key)
    {
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 
                                                        keyByteLength))
        {
            salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
            key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(keyByteLength);  
        }
    }
    public static bool IsValidPassword(string password, 
                                       byte[] salt, 
                                       byte[] key)
    {
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt))
        {
            byte[] newKey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(keyByteLength);  
            return newKey.SequenceEqual(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Of cource you can implement the algorithm of your own.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the type of feedback I was looking for... Regarding using Rfc2898DeriveBytes vs RNGCryptoServiceProvider and FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile... Which has the stronger hashing algorithm ? As far as getting a whole list of users, other methods actually handle getting the specific user to check the password against, the incUserID limits the password check to only that one, so I mean it does select against the whole database with only 1 return but the EntityFramework would do exactly the same thing wouldnt it?

Comment: @user1474120 - The main problem you are going to have is writting secure SQL queries.  Based on your own code, your not using a secure password schema which is a problem, but the getting the user and password in a secure way is a bigger problem.

Comment: @user1474120, take a look at [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/is-pbkdf2-based-system-cryptology-rfc2898derivebytes-better-for-unicode-pass)

Comment: "with only 1 return". Exactly. You need to get only one record from your database (select top 1 * from Accounts where AccountName = @accountName).

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but don't you not need the select top 1 if you have a unique constraint upon the userName? Or is it part of a security thing that i'm not aware of? (this is more than totally possible)